# Other cases similar to the 500 mile email problem?

Tags: networking, email

[The case of the 500-mile email](http://www.ibiblio.org/harris/500milemail.html) is a pretty odd case with a fun fix. Can you share other stories where the actual fault was something unexpected.

Perhaps it can help others who have some strange problem that they just can't figure out.

Answer (score 5):

I once heard of a serial port cable in a NY datacenter that kept getting unplugged. The punchline was it was being unplugged (and eventually cut!) by a union rep because the guy who had plugged it in (the owner and sysadmin of the equiment, visiting from another city) wasn't union labor.